# Why do I get unidentified label? (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android

I am getting a "unidentified label" error, here is my code:

```
if (this.prevTime > 0L)
    {
        int i = (int)(1.0E-06D * (System.nanoTime() - this.prevTime));
        if (i >= 2000)

            break label76;//unidentified label
        j = 3;
        if (j > 0)
            break label56;//unidentified label
        this.taps[0] = i;
    }
```

I also tried:

```
if (this.prevTime > 0L)
    {
        int i = (int)(1.0E-06D * (System.nanoTime() - this.prevTime));
        label76:
        if (i >= 2000)
            break label76;//'break' statement unnecessary
        j = 3;
        label56:
        if (j > 0)
            break label56;//'break' statement unnecessary
        this.taps[0] = i;
    }
```

but then I get ('break' statement unnecessary).

Comment: Your labels need to be visible in the same scope to be able to `break`/`goto` them :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1st case: you don't declare labels.
- 2nd case: the label is in the break scope so it's unnecessary

---

Labels must be placed in a line that makes sense and when the `break` statement is not enough.

Of course, you can refer to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) for further info:

> An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but **a labeled break terminates an outer statement**.

Look at this example: The following program, **BreakWithLabelDemo**, uses nested `for` loops to search for a value in a two-dimensional array. **When the value is found, a labeled `break` terminates the outer `for` loop (labeled "search"):**

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search: // <-----------------------------------------------------------*
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) { //                      *
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) { //               *
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) { //                   *
                    foundIt = true;  //                                    *
                    break search;  // -------------------------------------*
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```